# How to prompt android users to save the contact details directly into their Android device from a vCard file (vcf)

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a digital card system and trying to save a vcf file into an Android phone which should prompt the user to save contact details directly into their Android device. The following code is working on iPhone but not on Android devices.

```
<script>
  var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
  saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var contact = {
      name: "<?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?>",
      phone: "<?php echo $row["phone"]; ?>",
      email: "<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>",
      company: "<?php echo $row["company"]; ?>",
      socialpro: "<?php echo $row["city"]; ?>"
    };

    var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";

    var blob = new Blob([vcard], {
      type: "text/vcard"
    });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
    newLink.textContent = contact.name;
    newLink.href = url;

    newLink.click();

  });
</script>
```

**My work so far**

Please click on this link and you can able to save the contact on iPhone but it's not working on Android (http://mycontacts.unaux.com/displaycontact1.php?employee_id=1&genlist=list&i=4)

**Working website**

Please see the sample website (https://digicard.ae/oksana) and when you will click on Save to Contacts it's working for both Android and iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering with this code on Android devices may be related to the way that Android handles the download and saving of vCard files.

A possible solution is to trigger a download of the vCard file, but instead of directly opening the file, let the user decide where to save it. You can achieve this by using the "download" attribute on the link element and setting its value to the desired filename.

Try using this code and see if it worked:

```
<script>
  var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
  saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var contact = {
      name: "<?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?>",
      phone: "<?php echo $row["phone"]; ?>",
      email: "<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>",
      company: "<?php echo $row["company"]; ?>",
      socialpro: "<?php echo $row["city"]; ?>"
    };

    var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";

    var blob = new Blob([vcard], {
      type: "text/vcard;charset=utf-8"
    });

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
    link.click();

  });
</script>
```

This should allow the user to download the vCard file and choose where to save it on their Android device.

Comment: Thanks. It's download the file but when saving to contact it's saying "Something went wrong".

Comment: It's worked on Vivo phone but not on Sumsung phones. Any further help?

Comment: I don't have a Samsung phone so I can't really try it. Can you check on your Samsung documentation?